# Include a path in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How to include such a path in a table?

[image: table containing a path]

this is the code proposed by @Schrodinger's cat  with and the problem is when I changed "jeu" to "game" the result is not good:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
 nodes={minimum size=2.5em,draw,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=right,text width={width("game")}},
 row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=center},
 ] (mat) {
   & 0 & 15 & 30 & 40 & game \\
 0 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 15 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 30 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 40 &   &    &    &|[fill=green!70!black]|    &  \\
 game & |[fill=orange]|   &|[fill=orange]|   & |[fill=orange]| &    &  \\
 };
\draw[red,very thick] plot[mark=*] coordinates {
(mat-2-2) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) (mat-4-4) (mat-4-5) (mat-4-6)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pathlatex]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome! With a Ti*k*Z matrix it is very easy.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
 nodes={minimum size=2.5em,draw,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=right,text width={width("jeu")}},
 row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=center},
 ] (mat) {
   & 0 & 15 & 30 & 40 & jeu \\
 0 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 15 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 30 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 40 &   &    &    &|[fill=green!70!black]|    &  \\
 jeu & |[fill=orange]|   &|[fill=orange]|   & |[fill=orange]| &    &  \\
 };
\draw[red,very thick] plot[mark=*] coordinates {
(mat-2-2) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) (mat-4-4) (mat-4-5) (mat-4-6)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: A version that does not require you to set the text width of the first column yourself. You need to compile twice.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{column align/.style 2 args={column #1/.append style={nodes={execute at begin
node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
execute at end
node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][#2]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}}}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
 nodes={minimum size=3.25em,draw,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center},
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},column align={1}{r},
 row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=center},
 ] (mat) {
   & 0 & 15 & 30 & 40 & game \\
 0 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 15 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 30 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 40 &   &    &    &|[fill=green!70!black]|    &  \\
 game & |[fill=orange]|   &|[fill=orange]|   & |[fill=orange]| &    &  \\
 };
\draw[red,very thick] plot[mark=*] coordinates {
    (mat-2-2) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) (mat-4-4) (mat-4-5) (mat-4-6)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could play this game further to completely autosize the cells, if needed. Rather than doing this, here is a version in which you can specify the wides entry with `widest=game`, for example.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{widest/.style={nodes={minimum size={width("#1")+4*2pt+4*\pgflinewidth}},
column 1/.append style={nodes={text width={width("#1")}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
 nodes={draw,outer sep=0pt,anchor=center},widest=game,
 row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 column 1/.append style={nodes={draw=none},align=right},
 row 1/.append style={nodes={draw=none},align=center},
 ] (mat) {
   & 0 & 15 & 30 & 40 & game \\
 0 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 15 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 30 &   &    &    &    & |[fill=purple!30]| \\
 40 &   &    &    &|[fill=green!70!black]|    &  \\
 game & |[fill=orange]|   &|[fill=orange]|   & |[fill=orange]| &    &  \\
 };
\draw[red,very thick] plot[mark=*] coordinates {
(mat-2-2) (mat-2-3) (mat-3-3) (mat-3-4) (mat-4-4) (mat-4-5) (mat-4-6)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful.

Comment: cat
when I change "jeu" to "game" the last column is like isolated from the rest.

Comment: @Math512 In that case you need `column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none},align=right,text width={width("game")}},`, i.e. use the width of "game". One can, of course, automatize this with e.g. `eqparbox`.

Comment: I still have the same problem as shown in my last edit to the question

Comment: @Math512 Please see the lower code of my answer. (It would also be nice if you could mention where the code comes from.)

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mention your name before, and again thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way! Do you see plain TikZ code?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\fill[purple!30] (4,0)  rectangle +(1,-3);
\fill[cyan]      (3,-3) rectangle +(1,-1);
\fill[orange]    (0,-4) rectangle +(3,-1);
\draw (0,0) grid (5,-5);
\end{scope}

\draw[red,mark=*,line width=1.2pt] plot coordinates 
{(0,0) (1,0) (1,-1) (2,-1) (2,-2) (3,-2) (4,-2)};

\foreach \i/\j in {0/0,1/15,2/30,3/40,4/jeu}
\path (\i,1) node{\j} (-1,-\i) node{\j}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmmmmm, it's really interesting, I am new to the world of Tikz and I am already astonished by it. thank you @BLack for this new way.

Comment: @Math512 my advice is starting with plain TikZ, and try to write code with elegant simplicity